# Facebook debugger : Response 206

Tags: facebook, debugging

url: http://www.pagepilot.co.uk/pp_cftest/

When posted into facebook debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pagepilot.co.uk%2Fpp_cftest%2F

Keeps returning a 206 Partial Response Instead of a 200 OK

The code being returned is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<title>pp_cftest</title>
<meta property="og:title"       content="pp_cftest" />
<meta property="og:type"        content="company" />
<meta property="og:url"         content="http://www.pagepilot.co.uk/pp_cftest/" />
<meta property="og:site_name"   content="PagePilot" />
<meta property="og:description" content="description text" />
<meta property="fb:app_id"      content="242396009188876" />
<meta property="og:image"       content="http://www.pagepilot.co.uk/views/pp_w_en/assets/images/ladbrokes.gif" />
</head>
<body>
<p>test content</p>
</body>
</html>
```

There doesn't seem to be anything unusual or missing in the code. Just don't understand it.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The debugger only requests the first 40KB of your page - so the 206 is expected (well, it's expected if only part of the document was returned but i guess some servers return it for any request with a `Range:` header)

It shouldn't affect your ability to have the tags read correctly and the metadata populated when sharing a link on Facebook

Comment: Thank you Igy. Was concerned that this may be part of the reason why our like buttons have stopped working. Guess i'll need to look elsewhere.

Comment: That link shares fine for me by the way

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a facebook bug, basically when anyone clicks like on one of our client's pages, the like doesn't trigger a refresh. Though checking a basic page generated by our system would be a goo dway to see if it was anything in our system causing it.

Comment: Do you mean that the edge.create callback isn't being fired in the javascript SDK? or are you referring to a Page on facebook.com? if it's the first one, you should file a bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/ , if it's the second one, there's a tool here for feedback: https://www.facebook.com/KnownIssues?sk=app_4949752878

Comment: Hi igy. Thanks for your help. Turned out to be a legacy issue, a piece of code that worked around an issue in the previous php sdk. Now resolved. It manifested exactly as the fixed bug with the like button, which led us down a bit of a rabbit hole.