# Open Graph Object Debugger: Response Code 206

Tags: facebook, debugging

I updated my open graph image on the server and tried fetch the new scrape info with the facebook open graph tool https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/.

It does not update my pic and keeps giving a 206 Response Code instead of a 200.
The og: commands and the open graph tool worked fine before on that site.

This is what the scraper gets: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dnxglobal.com%2F.

All info in the `<head>` section seems to be okay.

Any hints? 
Thx so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Thx for the explanation.
It is the correct URL that is fetched, but not the correct image.

Oh yeah: I figured out how to work-around.

If you rename the og:image it fetches the new picture.
Remaining the same filename the facebook scraper does not refresh the server.

THX

Answer (score 0):

The error code 206 is no problem; it's because the Facebook scraper only get a partial content. See also: [Facebook debugger : Response 206](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807771/facebook-debugger-response-206)

The scraper currently shows the following url for og:image, which is the same as you have defined in your head. Which url are you expecting to see?

http://www.dnxglobal.com/assets/pictures/dnx-global-og-image.jpg